# find with -execdir does not execute command

Tags: bash, gcc, find

I am trying to write a script to read in a list of source files and compile them with `gcc` using this command: `find $source -name '*.c' -or -name '*.cpp' -execdir gcc {} -o $output \;` I am able to find the source files, but they are not compiled with `gcc`. What do I have to do to actually be able to compile them?

Comment: What is the value of `$output` ?

Comment: I just used a test path such as `/home/user/Desktop/file.out`

Comment: For me it worked. I've tested with simple 'void main() {}' files. This shows that the `find` command itself is working.

Comment: I found what causes the problem. I had `-or -name '*.cpp'` added to the `find` expression as well, and that causes `-execdir` to not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-execdir` action is evaluated as part of the expression. `-a` takes precedence over `-o`, so to `find` the expression reads like:

```
find $source \( -name '*.c' \) -or \( -name '*.cpp' -execdir gcc {} -o $output \; \)
```

You need to add parentheses to your expression to force `find` to behave as you want:

```
find $source \( -name '*.c' -or -name '*.cpp' \) -execdir gcc {} -o $output \;
```

Some simpler examples:

```
# touch a b
# find . -name a -o -name b -print
./b
# find . -name a -print -o -name b
./a
# find . \( -name a -o -name b \) -print
./b
./a
```